# How to populate a charts.js pie chart using json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, charts, chart.js

My json array looks like this

```
[{"count":2,"DepartementNom":"Finance"},{"count":1,"DepartementNom":"Technique"}]
```

How can I populate a chart.js pie chart using that dataset?
I've tried this code but there seems to be a problem with it somewhere.

```
    var d = {!! json_encode($json_deco) !!};
new Chart(document.getElementById("pie-chart"), {
    type: 'pie',
    data: d,
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Nombre demployés par departement"
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it that way. [Here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) in the documentation there are some examples

One of the simple ways to set the data for a chart can be done that way:

```
data: {
        labels: ['Finance', 'Technique'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [1, 2],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edicarlos10/ny2o9wcg/2/) example